# Holidays in Salesforce Calendar

Tags: calendar

Is there any way to add public holidays on salesforce calendar other than using the holiday object?
The only other way I see it is to add it as a public calendar, but it doesn't seem to be a great solution as we have different countries that are a part of our project.

Comment: Can you eleborate more on what's the exact use case of this and what limitation are you facing with Holiday Object? @PriyamSri28

Comment: So in salesforce, I want to show the public holidays / bank holidays on the calendar for every user based on the country they are in. Right now, the only option I have is to use the holiday object and create a calendar for the same, but the look and feel isn't great, plus this solution is not good in long run. So I was wondering if there is another way to do the same. @subankhoja